# Test POST method that return ResponseEntity<> in Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-test

I'm trying to test my POST method that returns ResponseEntity<> in service class:

```
public ResponseEntity<Customer> addCustomer(Customer customer) {
    [validation etc...]
    return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.save(customer), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

What I'm doing:

```
    @Test
public void addCustomer() throws Exception {
    String json = "{" +
            "\"name\": \"Test Name\"," +
            "\"email\": \"test@email.com\"" +
            "}";

    Customer customer = new Customer("Test Name", "test@email.com");

    when(service.addCustomer(customer))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(customer, HttpStatus.OK));

    this.mockMvc.perform(post(CustomerController.URI)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(json)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").exists())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("Test Name")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is("test@email.com")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(3)))
            .andDo(print());
}
```

When I run the test I've receiving:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id"
```

and Status = 200. So as far as I understand Mockito is not returning the object. The other methods like GET work perfectly fine, but they return the object, not the ResponseEntity<>. What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix that?

Comment: The object you told it to return has no id.

Comment: Does initializing `Customer` automatically assign an `id`?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Whole return body is empty. I've checked all possibilities: when adding id - gives the same error, when remove expect id then return that there is no name value.

Comment: Could you show us the equals() and hashCode() implementations of your Customer class as Mockito relies on equals() when matching arguments.

Comment: Even I too tried I am getting the same error for post request, I need a help if there is a problem with Mockito that it won't return ResponseEntity<> object or any resolution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have created a `Customer` in test code, this `Customer` is different from the `Customer` in production code.

So Mockito cannot match the two `Customer`, and cause `when/thenReturn` expression to fail. Thus `service.addCustomer` return a `null` and you get AssertionError in test result.

You can use `any()` matcher to  solve this problem:

```
when(service.addCustomer(any())).thenReturn(.....);
```